# How do I insert content after a block of text using prototype.js?

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs

I am trying to insert a block of html code using prototype.js

I have been able to do this when I target an html element such as

```
$('footer').insert({top: '<div id="footer_inner"><small>CompanyName, LLC</small></div>'})
```

Is it possible to inset a div after text such as

#### James McCarthy (level3)

Is it possible to target the text level3? and insert a block html after it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Just use `after` as the first parameter for `insert()`:

```
$('level3').insert({after: '<p>HTML goes here</p>'});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. So simple I was over thinking it. Thanks again.